# Toggle button, button class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bom estou tentando fazer um toggle button, mas estou com um problema 
o button que eu quero precisa de uma class pra estilizar no css.

```
button class="button button1">Shadow Button</button
```

, mas o codigo de toggle button que peguei usa uma type no button

```
button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button
```

como eu faço para chamar esse onClick nesse button com class:

```
button class="button button1">Shadow Button</button
```

Comment: Não entendi, por que você não acrescenta o onclick além das classes?

Comment: button class="button button1" onclick="myFunction()">Shadow Button</button

Comment: ficaria assim??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal Felipe:

```
<button type="QUALQUER TIPO (button, submit etc)" onclick="QUALQUER FUNCAO PODE SER CHAMADA AQUI (alert, myfunction etc)" class="QUALQUER CLASSE (button btn btntoogle etc")> meu botao</button>
```

No HTML5 você pode por funções de on click e adicionar classes em quase todos os elementos